# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln a$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Without using L'Hopital's rule, prove that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln a$$

Comment: What is your definition of $\ln a$?

Comment: @MarkBennet: Natural logarithm

Comment: yes, but what is natural logarithm, how is it defined?

Comment: The natural logarithm can be defined - and is defined in some approaches - by the limit you are computing. Sometimes it is defined as an integral. All the definitions prove to be equivalent, but the point is, which definition are you using, because that affects how you might go about proving the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if that is rigorous enough for you, but this is one way using $e^t = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!}$, $e^{\ln x} = x$ and some results about absolute convergent series:

\begin{align*}
\frac{a^x - 1}{x} & = (e^{x \cdot \ln a} -1)/x = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x \cdot \ln a)^k}{k!} - 1 \right)/x\\
& = \left( x \cdot \ln a + \frac{(x \cdot \ln a)^2}{2} + \ldots \right)/x = \ln a + (\ln a)^2 \cdot \frac{x}{2} + (\ln a)^3 \cdot \frac{x^2}{6} +\ldots\\
\end{align*}

Hence, $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x -1}{x} = \ln a$.

Comment: May I suggest you write $x\cdot\log a$ instead of $\log a\cdot x$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sure thing, edited it. Thank you for the note.

Comment: Thanks for doing it ! The initial writing could have been slightly confusing. Cheers :-)